# ActionBarSherlock list navigation with icon and title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am developing an application where navigation is done by using the spinner on the action bar. Spinner items needed to include icons as well so I created custom layouts for that.The problem is that spinner is too wide with respect to its items. I am using ActionBarSherlock. The codes I wrote so far:

**navigation_list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="4dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="?attr/spinnerItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**navigation_list_dropdown_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="4dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**NavigationListAdapter.java:**

```
public class NavigationListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Drawable[] mIcons;
    private String[] mTitles;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public NavigationListAdapter(Context context, Drawable[] icons, String[] titles){
        mContext = context;
        mInflator = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mIcons = icons;
        mTitles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTitles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.navigation_list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mTitles[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mIcons[position]);

        return convertView;
    }   

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.navigation_list_dropdown_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(mTitles[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mIcons[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        public ImageView icon;
        public TextView title;
    }
}
```

**onCreate method of the activity:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
        TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.leagues);
        Drawable[] logos = new Drawable[ta.length()];
        for(int i = 0; i < logos.length; i++){
            logos[i] = ta.getDrawable(i);
        }

        NavigationListAdapter adapter = new NavigationListAdapter(context, logos, 
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.league_names));

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, null);
    }
```

An illustration of the problem:
[image]

Comment: Could it be as simple as not setting `android:layout_width` to `wrap_content` in navigation_list_dropdown_item.xml?

Comment: no luck. it makes this even worse because width does not change but dropdown items can only be selected when their titles or icons are clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe changing the width of your textview in navigation_list_dropdown_item.xml to wrap_content take effect (if changing width of LinearLayout does not work). You can see this to: http://dandar3.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/actionbarsherlock-custom-list-navigation.html .